# How can I make this custom tag work as expected?

Tags: java, jsp, tags, taglib, custom-tags

So this is the custom tag I have in the jsp file:

```
<myTags:myTag name="John">
    Value of k: ${valueOfK}
    <br />
</myTags:myTag>
```

And the Tag Handler Class I have:

```
@Override
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    getJspContext().getOut().print("<table>");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        getJspContext().getOut().print("<tr>");
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            getJspContext().getOut().print("<td>" + name + "</td>");
            getJspContext().setAttribute("valueOfK",k);
        }
        getJspBody().invoke(null);
        getJspContext().getOut().print("</tr>");
    }
    getJspContext().getOut().print("</table>");
}
```

So the output will be:

```
Value of k: 
Value of k: 0
Value of k: 1
Value of k: 2
Value of k: 3
Value of k: 4
Value of k: 5
Value of k: 6
Value of k: 7
Value of k: 8
John
John    John
John    John    John
John    John    John    John
John    John    John    John    John
John    John    John    John    John    John
John    John    John    John    John    John    John
John    John    John    John    John    John    John    John
John    John    John    John    John    John    John    John    John
```

But what I want to achieve is something like:

```
John Value of k: 1
John John Value of k: 2
```

etc...

Why are all the k values printed first and then the table is constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a custom tag whereas the same thing you can achieve using build-in JSTL tags.

sample code:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach begin="1" end="10" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <c:forEach begin="1" end="${status.index}">
                    John&nbsp;
                </c:forEach>
                Value of k: ${status.index}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

output:

```
John  Value of k: 1  
John  John  Value of k: 2  
John  John  John  Value of k: 3  
John  John  John  John  Value of k: 4  
John  John  John  John  John  Value of k: 5  
John  John  John  John  John  John  Value of k: 6  
John  John  John  John  John  John  John  Value of k: 7  
John  John  John  John  John  John  John  John  Value of k: 8  
John  John  John  John  John  John  John  John  John  Value of k: 9  
John  John  John  John  John  John  John  John  John  John  Value of k: 10
```

---

If you need same thing in multiple jsp then move the code in a separate JSP file and just include it wherever needed.

```
<jsp:include page="mytags.jsp">
    <jsp:param value="Koray" name="name" />
</jsp:include>
```

mytags.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<table>
    <c:forEach begin="1" end="10" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td><c:forEach begin="1" end="${status.index}">
                        ${param.name}&nbsp;
                    </c:forEach> Value of k: ${status.index}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

---

If you want to do using custom tag then try with [`BodyTagSupport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/BodyTagSupport.html) that implements [`BodyTag`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/BodyTag.html) interface.

[image]

sample code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport;

public class MyTag extends BodyTagSupport {

    private String name;
    private int counter;

    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
        counter = 1;
        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
        try {
            out.print(name);
            pageContext.setAttribute("valueOfK", counter);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
    }

    public int doAfterBody() {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 10) {
            return SKIP_BODY;
        } else {
            JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
            try {
                StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
                for (int k = 0; k < counter; k++) {
                    names.append(name).append(" ");
                }
                out.print(names.toString());
                pageContext.setAttribute("valueOfK", counter);
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return EVAL_BODY_AGAIN;
        }
    }

    public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
        return EVAL_PAGE;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause for the output is that "Value of k: 1" is not in a td tag. What's happening to the output is that any text inside the table tag which does not come inside a td tag is pushed to the beginning of the table as in your case. Look at the generated html source and you will find it to be true.

Now you have the root cause so I suppose you can work up on the solution... Cheers

Here is what should work for you

dont print Value of k: from your jsp

```
<myTags:myTag name="John">
    <%--Value of k: ${valueOfK}
    <br />--%>
</myTags:myTag>
```

instead, put it in your tag class

```
@Override
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    getJspContext().getOut().print("<table>");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        getJspContext().getOut().print("<tr>");
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            getJspContext().getOut().print("<td>" + name + "</td>");
            getJspContext().getOut().print("<td>Value of k: " + (k + 1) + "</td>");
            getJspContext().setAttribute("valueOfK",k);
        }
        getJspBody().invoke(null);
        getJspContext().getOut().print("</tr>");
    }
    getJspContext().getOut().print("</table>");
}
```